# Magento 2 reindex doesn't work after import

Tags: magento-2.1, import, reindex

I have 1000 products with custom attributes and multiselect ittributes info.
start import it give me message "Import successfully done".
After my attributes doesn't work in frontend. I make commands:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean

Product EAV Index product EAV - not change.
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '48-152-1-62' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_eav_idx` (`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

**How correct to add costom attributes?**
My products all simple. I put my all attributes to `additional_attributes` table slot:

```
material_table=wood|metall|plastic,color_table=red|green,p_table=8|16|32
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your importer add attribute every time it runs? It looks like it's trying to add the same product attribute(s).

Comment: I check without custom attributes and all works. Write please how aorrect to add custom attributes please.

Comment: It'd be easier if you share your importer code to suggest some solution to you.